# SQLiteQueryBuiler.setProjectionMap() doesn't affect where clause

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have an Android app with a `ContentProvider` class that queries two tables, `users` and `items`.

`users` table has the following columns:

```
_id (primary key)
online (integer)
```

`items` table has the following columns:

```
_id (primary key)
user_id (foreign key, maps to users._id)
name (text)
```

I then have a query that returns the result of the two tables joined together. In my `ContentProvider`, I use this code to map the column names:

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
queryBuilder.setTables("items INNER JOIN users ON users._id=items.user_id"); 
Map<String, String> columnMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
columnMap.put("item_id", "items._id");
columnMap.put("user_id", "items.user_id");
columnMap.put("user_online", "users.online");
columnMap.put("item_name", "items.name");
queryBuilder.setProjectionMap(columnMap);
```

However, when I perform the following query, to find all items which are owned by online users:

```
String[] projection = {"item_name"};
String selection = "user_online=1";
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, null, null);
```

I get the following exception:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: user_online (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT items.name FROM items INNER JOIN users ON users._id=items.user_id WHERE (user_online=1)
```

The problem appears to be that `setProjectionMap()` affects `projection`, but not `selection`.

Is there any other way of solving this problem, short of performing string manipulation on the projection to map the column names manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setProjectionMap` is needed only because it allows to the *output* column names of the query.

What you do in the selection is not visible in the resulting cursor, and in any case `SQLiteQueryBuilder` is not smart enough to parse SQL and replace the correct column names.

Just use the original column names:

```java
String selection = "users.online=1";
```

To make column aliases available in the selection, create a view for your join:

```
CREATE VIEW user_items AS
SELECT items._id AS item_id,
       items.user_id AS user_id,
       users.online AS user_online,
       items.name AS item_name
FROM items INNER JOIN users ON users._id=items.user_id;
```

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the purpose of `setProjectionMap`? I wanted to make the table appear to clients as being standalone (as if there were no `users` or `items` tables), is this not possible using the built-in methods?

Comment: The purpose of `setProjectionMap` is to affect only the projection.

Comment: I see, thanks. In that case, when is `setProjectionMap` ever useful, if the client always needs to know the original columns names anyway?

Comment: Apparently, clients are not supposed to use such columns.